# Jquery menu Anchor onBlur event disables Div sub anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I am new to JQuery Development. I am facing a issue with the `onblur` event, while i am trying to make a custom menu for my website.  could any one help me with this please.

Please find ths JS fiddle [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4LJh)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showmenu').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.focus();
        $('#serviceMenu').slideToggle("fast");
        $('#Contact').hide();
    });

    $('#showmenu').blur(function (e) {
        $('#serviceMenu').hide();
    });
});
```

The issue is that the show/hide div mechanism is based on a `<a>` tag. on clicking `<a>` the menu is toggling fine. i also want menu to toggle, when the user clicks anywhere outside the menu and the appearing div. In the fiddle i have added `onblur()` event for the anchor, that is making my sub links inside the div trigger `onblur()` event of main anchor, and hiding the menu. I tried to block `event.propagation()`, but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that the blur event is called, BEFORE you click on a#serviceMenu
You also should learn how the event-propagation works: [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
 I updated your fiddle (with some comments): http://jsfiddle.net/M4LJh/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showmenu').on('click', function (e) {
        this.focus();
        $('#serviceMenu').slideToggle("fast");
        $('#Contact').hide();
        return false;
    });

    // prevent clickEvent to bubble up to #showmenu
    $('#serviceMenu a').on('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation();});

    // hide #serviceMenu on bodyClick
    //    - anywhere but an element with propagation stopped event
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#serviceMenu').hide();
        return false; // e.stopPropagtaion(); + e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked. but still not smooth in IE9, IE9 sliding down with flickering.

Comment: The Menu is working fine when i change slideToggle()  to toggle(). But now  obviously the slide effect is missing.